# How to find autocorrelation value using Durbin Watson Test?

Tags: r

How can I get autocorrelation value using Durbin Watson test? when durbin watson test was done using `dwtest()`I i got this as answer.

```
fit <- lm(eruptions ~ waiting, faithful.data)
dwtest(fit)
 >Durbin-Watson test
 +data:  fit
 +DW = 2.561, p-value = 1
 +alternative hypothesis: true autocorrelation is greater than 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the variable and then extract it. For example:

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)
dw <- dwtest(fit)
dw$statistic
#      DW 
#1.669691
```

Comment: I found this problem when working out a question, the answer I got for DW is 2.561.. and the correct answer given for autocorrelation value is -0.2865..

Comment: This is the only value that the package returns. I do not know where this -0.2865 comes from. You would need to provide us with more information in order to help.

Comment: Is the value of DW and autocorrelation same -0.2865.. is the value of autocorrelation